# VBA how to pass named range Name into a formula rather than a cell content

Tags: loops, excel, range, named, vba

I have 3 ranges, "AA", "AB", and "AC".

The *names* of these ranges are on sheet 1 in column A.. so....

Cell A1 contains two letters "AA"
Cell A2 contains AB
Cell A3 contains AC

I need a formula to go down this list (A1:A3) and pull in the names of the ranges and paste them on another sheet.

I am able to achieve this with this code:

```
Range("AA").Copy Sheets(2).Range("B6")
```

Now I need a way to substitute the "AA" for a dynamic range such as Cell(c,r) so the formula can go down the list...because the names of these named ranges will change in other spreadsheets so I can't hardcode them.

Thank you for any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the name in cell A1,

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names([A1].Value).RefersToRange.Copy
```

will achieve the same copy as your snippet.

Comment: Would I be able to use Cell(i,1) instead of "A1" and then make it part of a loop where each step is i=i+1 so it would go down a list an pull in new cell info?

Comment: Yes, you can use ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value in place of [A1].Value